# Encrypt with Double Length 3DES Key in Java and produce 16 bytes array cipher

Tags: java, encryption, 3des

I need to create a double length 3DES key in Java using a 16 bytes array key material, encrypt with it a message and get back 16 bytes length array. I am able to get it working with 24 bytes but not 16 bytes...

Because DESede expects 24 byte[], the only way to produce a double length 3DES Key with a 16 bytes long key material, I was able to by using a DESede instance and then increasing its length by appending first 8 bytes at the end to get 24 bytes. Like so:

```
    byte[] keyMaterial = // Assume this one is 16 bytes. 

    byte[] newKeyBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap( new byte[ 24 ] )
            .put( Arrays.copyOfRange( keyMaterial, 0, 16 ) )
            .put( Arrays.copyOfRange( keyMaterial, 0, 8 ) )
            .array();

    SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "DESede" );
    KeySpec myKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec( newKeyBytes );
    SecretKey encryptionKey = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret( myKeySpec );
```

Now when I have my DESede key I can use it to encrypt the message the following way. Also, I need to use "ECB" mode:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding" );
    cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey );
    byte[] returnValue = cipher.doFinal( dataToEncrypt )
```

But as a result I get back 24 byte array rather than 16 byte array and I guess this is because I am encrypting with 24 byte array.

Is there a way to create a 3DES SecretKey 16 bytes long rather than 24 bytes, OR when encrypting with 24 byte long SecretKey, get back a 16 bytes long ciphered message as I need rather than 24 bytes long?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have just found an answer to my question.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

I used DESede/ECB/NoPadding and when used with NoPadding, then encrypting a 16 bytes array message with 24 bytes SecretKey produces a 16 bytes long cipher message which is exactly what I need.

I hope this finding is correct. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: This is correct. Remember that key size has little to do with the block size; while encrypting *the key size isn't reflected in the result at all*. **Going deeper**: Obviously having a key size that is a multiple of the block size is still usefull, for instance when *wrapping* (encrypting) keys themselves. This is one drawback of AES-192; it's 1.5 times the block size - often reason enough not to consider it.